# NullPointerException when checking for permissions

Tags: java, android

I was trying to obtain runtime permissions for Android. I tried to create a class called `RequestPermissions` which extends `MainActivity`. However I get this error when asking for permissions since I wanted to separate the permission request code from `MainActvity`:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Context.checkPermission(java.lang.String, int, int)' on a null object reference

Below are the classes

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  }
}
```

**RequestPermission.java**

```
public class RequestPermissions extends MainActivity {

 private static final int SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

 public RequestPermissions() {
    checkAndRequestForPermissions()
  }

  void checkAndRequestForPermissions() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
          ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
  }

  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
// Do something here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: in manifest permission is there or not?

Comment: Why you are calling it in the constructor? You should call it inside `onCreate` or any other lifecycle method

Comment: @Vishalkumarsinghvi yes, i have added it in the permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're requesting permissions too early. In the code:

```
public RequestPermissions() {
    checkAndRequestForPermissions();
}
```

You're checking for permissions as the `RequestPermissions` class is being constructed, which is before the [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) has begun. Therefore the `Context` does not yet exist.

You'll need to move `checkAndRequestForPermissions()` into a lifecycle method, for example `onResume()` as the user may have manually revoked permissions while your app was minimised. For example:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    checkAndRequestForPermissions();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

to

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
```